# Is it possible to get the type of variable to be assigned via reflection?

Tags: c#

I was wondering something like the the following is possible

```
int foo = GetDefaultValue();

object GetDefaultValue() // Example function, behavior is not the purpose of this question
{
    Type t = // Reflection magic
    if (t.IsValueType)
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    return null;
}
```

I know something similar exists with the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` attribute, but it doesn't give me what I'm looking for.

I know I can use generics, pass type as parameter etc, but I was curious if it's possible with reflection (just curiosity)

Comment: You can just use int foo = default;. Why You want to do yourself it via reflection?

Comment: Simple answer: no. Of course what you're doing here is already part of the language (`int foo = default`), which works only courtesy of the language defining the context-aware behavior that way (earlier versions required `int foo = default(int)`). There is no generic mechanism for passing context like "the type of the variable that the result of this call is going to be assigned to, if any", nor, arguably, is that really desirable since it hides things. For most cases being explicit is still best (`GetDefaultValue<T>`, then use `typeof(T)`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Did I misunderstand, or should that last thing be `default(T)` instead of `typeof(T)`?

Comment: @Flater: no, I meant `typeof(T)` -- since `GetDefaultValue` is just an example (per the OP's comment), if you want to implement generic functionality that takes the type into consideration somehow you'd end up with a `typeof(T)` invocation somewhere. `GetDefaultValue` itself is, as already mentioned, completely superfluous and you'd never write it in the first place (the perils of picking a bad example). Well, except maybe if you need to wrap `default` as a delegate, but even then you can just write `T GetDefaultValue<T>() => default`, no `default(T)` needed.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comments, default values are already part of the language:

```
int myInteger = default;
```

You don't need anything extra for this.

> I know I can use generics, pass type as parameter etc, but I was curious if it's possible with reflection (just curiosity)

Reflection *on what*?

You're not passing anything. Reflection either involves instantiation based on a dynamically passed type, or typing/accessing properties based on a dynamically passed object.

But you're not providing a type *or* an instance, so there is nothing to reflect on here.